# Logo is shifted to the left because of the Hamburger-Icon on the right

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In advance, I apologize for my bad English.

My logo (which should be positioned in the horizontal center on the header) gets shifted like 5px to the left.

The hamburger icon is also like 5px wide, so I tested what would happen if I set the hamburger icon property `display:none;` and the logo shifted perfectly to the horizontal center.

I already set the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties for the logo to `auto` and it works fine, except for the 5px shift to the left.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

I'm grateful for any answer.

```html
<div
    class="fusion-header-v6 fusion-logo-center fusion-sticky-menu- fusion-sticky-logo- fusion-mobile-logo-  fusion-header-has-flyout-menu">
    <div class="fusion-header-sticky-height"></div>
    <div class="fusion-header">
        <div class="fusion-row">
            <div class="fusion-header-v6-content fusion-header-has-flyout-menu-content">
                <div class="fusion-logo" data-margin-top="31px" data-margin-bottom="31px" data-margin-left=""
                    data-margin-right="0px">
                    <a class="fusion-logo-link" href="#">

                        <!-- standard logo -->
                        <img src="link" srcset="link 1x" width="2792" height="1216" retina_logo_url=""
                            class="fusion-standard-logo" />


                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="fusion-flyout-menu-icons">



                    <a class="fusion-flyout-menu-toggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Toggle Menu" href="#">
                        <div class="fusion-toggle-icon-line"></div>
                        <div class="fusion-toggle-icon-line"></div>
                        <div class="fusion-toggle-icon-line"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey HewlettPackard :o). Can you also provide your css code ?

Comment: Absolutely position the hamburger icon.

Comment: @RémyTesta. I can't find the css file which is responsible for the header. I made a screenshot of every class css and uploaded it here: [link](http://imgur.com/a/Pz3W6uL)

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo This did not work :/

Comment: Without css is difficult to understand how your website works.